# Installation Recommendations For Dual-Booting Win 7 & Arch Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, grub, arch-linux, multi-boot

I want to install both Windows 7 and Arch Linux on my 1 TB HDD so that the partitions look like so:

```
grub name | lin name | label                 | fs   | mount point
----------------------------------------------------------------------
hd0,0     | sda1     | System Reserved (win) | ntfs |
hd0,1     | sda2     | Windows 7             | ntfs | /media/Win7
hd0,2     | sda3     | Arch Linux Boot       | ext2 | /boot
hd0,3     | sda4     | Arch Linux Swap       | swap | 
hd0,4     | sda5     | Arch Linux Root       | ext4 | /
hd0,5     | sda6     | Arch Linux Home       | ext4 | /home
hd0,6     | sda7     | Stuff                 | ntfs | /media/Stuff
```

Is this even possible? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I suggest removing the system reserved partition, its a waste of space and a partition...http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/08/20/hack-to-remove-100-mb-system-reserved-partition-when-installing-windows-7/

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet will be to use GRUB or LILO and configure them as a bootloader allowing you to select either your Windows install or your Linux install.

There is an excellent tutorial for GRUB at the ArchLinux website:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Windows_and_Arch_Dual_Boot

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You should start by [Reading The Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Windows_and_Arch_Dual_Boot)

### Preparation

#### a) If your laptop comes with Win7 preinstalled:

1. Backup. (Seriously.)
2. Defrag your windows partition.
3. Resize the windows 7 ntfs partition using [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php)
4. In the created free space, create two primary partitions, one for Arch, one for Stuff.

#### b) If you are reinstalling Win7:

1. Using gparted Split the free space on your drive into three primary partitions (One for Win7, one for arch, one for Stuff)
2. Install Windows on the first primary partition (this won't create a system reserved partition). Read the prompts carefully while installing, or Win7 will gobble up all your disk.

### Installation

1. In gparted, create extended partitions for `/boot`, `swap`, `/home` and `/` within the Arch primary partition.
2. Write the partitions to disk.
3. Boot into the arch install CD/USB
4. Install arch in the created partitions
5. During the Arch linux installation, you'll be prompted about where you wish to install your boot loader. IMPORTANT: Select the master boot record, `MBR`.
6. When given the option to edit your Grub config, add windows as one of the options. You can learn more about your Grub config by [reading the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB).

#### Done!